# Extract information from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
movies['genres'].head()
```

where each line looks like:

```
   0     [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
1    [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
2                                     [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
3        [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
4                                                                       [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
Name: genres, dtype: object
```

I would like to save it in a data frame where one column is 'id' and the rows are the id values and another column 'name' where the rows are the name values. I tried with:

```
pd.DataFrame(movies['genres'])
```

However when I ran it I obtained:

```
        genres
0   [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
1   [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
2   [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
```

Could you help me?
Regards

Comment: Can you edit your question so that I can easily replicate the output? Currently I don't see the object `movies` defined in your question, but  this object is central to your question. Also, for convenience, it'd be great if you definition of `movies` could be easily replicated in my interpreter by copying the relevant portion of code from your question. Thanks!

Comment: What is the first structure ? List of dictionnaries or list of list of dictionaries ? Please share some data exactly as they are

Comment: I edited the question. I'm not sure if it is a list of dictionaries or list of list of dictionaries, I'm new with this. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the command `.from_dict()` as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(movies["genres"])
```